MySQL NodeJS Cron Alternative
I have a project where I have a orders table. Here, every 10 seconds, I send newly arrived orders to the mobile application, other API services, and internal services. However, in doing so, I'm currently using Node.js to send a SELECT query to the database every 10 seconds, which puts a lot of load on the database. Is there an alternative solution I can use?
Installing Redis crossed my mind, but it's installed on multiple hosts and it's not feasible for me to set it up right now.

One query every 10 seconds shouldn't cause significant load. I suspect that query is just poorly optimized, and you might be able to improve it with a well-chosen index. That's just a guess, though, because you haven't shown any SQL.

Mysql has no notification services, so you either have to do polling or you need to use an alternative solution like redis. If you use polling, then scheduler running the code is irrelevant.

Thank you for your answers. @BillKarwin yes you are right I will include the SQL query here again soon.
